# Is reading Qur'an fard?

Tags: reading-quran, fard

Is reading Qur'an fard? If so, what kind of fard is it (e.g every Muslim must, or some Muslim must?). If not, what is it categorized as? Is it sunnah or wajib or anything else?

Please don't answer with reading Qur'an is good for you, and every Muslim should read Qur'an, I know that. I am looking for technical point of view.

(Hanafi point of view preffered, but other sects/schools opinion is also welcome)

Comment: what you mean by technical?!

Comment: @Ahmadi I mean, fard, or sunnah or ... (I guess it is called fiqh?)

Comment: OK. I improved my answer. Fiqh means detailed rules for every act and not about main beliefs (which relates to sect). for example Jafari Fiqh is used by both shia and sunni.

Comment: Allah is **talking** to us in Quran. And us (his slaves) questioning whether listening to him is fard or sunnah doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Jafari Fiqh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ja%27fari_jurisprudence) reading Quran is not Fard (Obligatory) but it is highly recommended (Mustahab Mu'akkad).

> In the Shari'ah (Islamic Constitution) deeds and actions are divided
>   into five classes:
>
> Fardh or Wajib:   فرض او واجـب  An obligatory duty the omission of
>   which is Islamicly punishable.
>
> Mus'tahab:  مسـتـحب  An action which is rewarded, but whose omission
>   is not punishable.
>
> Mu'baah::     مـباحAn action which is permitted but legally is
>   indifferent.
>
> Mak'rooh: مكـروه   An action which is disapproved by the Shari'ah but
>   is not under any penalty.
>
> Haram:  An action which is forbidden, and Islamicly punishable.
>   ([Reference](http://www.islamic-laws.com/hadithoverview.htm))

Reading Quran is an Action and Sunnah means practices of prophet Muhammad (PBUH) that can be Wajib or Mustahab or Mubah. (Prophet was infallible and never did any Makruh or haram). sometimes Sunnah is used as meaning of Mustahab but this is general and not technical.

> The Messenger of Allah (blessings of Allah be upon him and his family)
>   has said: “The best of those amongst you is the one who learns the
>   Qur’an and then teaches it to others.”

Al-Amali of Shaykh at-Tusi, Volume 1, Page 5

> Imam Ja’far ibne Muhammad as-Sadiq (peace be upon him) has said: “The
>   Qur’an is the trust of Allah (given) to His creations, therefore it is
>   desirable for every Muslim to look at this trust and to  recite (a
>   minimum of) 50 ayat (verses) of the Qur’an everyday.”

Usulul Kafi, Volume 2, Page 609

> Imam Ja’far ibne Muhammad as-Sadiq (peace be upon him) has said that:
>   “Reciting the Qur’an from the pages of the Qur’an (meaning to look at
>   it and recite it - not from memory) lightens the punishment of one’s
>   mother and father, even if they are both disbelievers.”

Usulul Kafi, Volume 2, Page 613

---

**References and more info about reading Quran:**

[40 Hadith - The Noble Qur'an](http://www.al-islam.org/40hadithquran/)

[http://makarem.ir](http://makarem.ir/websites/english/estefta/?it=1067%22)

Comment: +1 good focused answer.

Answer (score 3):

(This is a general answer. I do not believe in any sect in Islam)
The thing that is legislated for the Muslim is for him to **consistently and frequently** recite the Qur’an, to a degree that he is capable of.
There are verses from the Quran that tell us to read the Quran-

> **Recite, [O Muhammad], what has been revealed to you of the Book** and establish prayer. Indeed, prayer prohibits immorality and wrongdoing, and the remembrance of Allah is greater. And Allah knows that which you do. [29:45] (Sahih International)
>
> [Say, O Muhammad], "I have only been commanded to worship the Lord of this city, who made it sacred and to whom [belongs] all things. **And I am commanded to be of the Muslims [those who submit to Allah] And to recite the Qur'an.**" And whoever is guided is only guided for [the benefit of] himself; and whoever strays - say, "I am only [one] of the warners." [27:91-92] (Sahih International)

In both these verses Allah tells Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) to recite the Quran so who are we compared to him.

The conclusion is that it is not compulsory but it is recommended because

1. We come to know about God's words.
2. We will always follow the right path, away from Satan.

   > The Messenger of Allah (blessings of Allah be upon him and his family) has said: “Nothing is harder for Satan to bear than a person who recites the Qur’an by looking at the pages (of the Qur’an).” [Thawabul A’mal, Page 231]
3. Lastly we will not be branded a disbeliever as stated by this verse

   > O my Lord! Verily, my people deserted this Qur’an (neither listened to it, nor acted upon its laws and orders). [25:30]

May Allah guide you onto the right path. Ameen.

Comment: Is there a source for this answer?

Comment: @ansari not at all. i wrote it on my own. God promise :)