# Do I have to read Quran everyday?

Tags: quran

The most time I read Quran is on ramadan. Do we have to read it everyday or if we wanted to read it anytime we can?

Another question. Do we need to memorize the Quran ?

Comment: Reading Quran is not fard but to follow it, and it is not fard to memorize quran.and allah knows best.

Comment: This should answer part of your question: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/is-reading-quran-fard